How to add gemini tuned model to my app in android studio
I am developing a mobile emergency app for Android as part of my computer engineering thesis. I have integrated the Gemini API to create a first aid assistance system, and I have already generated an API key and tested the initial code.
My problem is that the model responds to any input, not just emergencies. I tried to solve it by creating a prompt with a specific dataset for emergencies, generating a tuned model. However, by changing the modelName parameter inside GenerativeModel gm = new GenerativeModel(modelName, apiKey); to the ID of the generated tuned model tunedModels/first-aid-123example123, the tuned model does not give any answers.
How should I adjust the code to use the tuned model instead of the standard Gemini generative model?
This is my actual code:
//imports

public class AssistanceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText emergencyInput;
    private TextView responseView;
    private Button sendButton;
    private GenerativeModelFutures model;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_assistance);

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        emergencyInput = findViewById(R.id.emergencyInput);
        responseView = findViewById(R.id.response);
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.send);

        GenerativeModel gm = new GenerativeModel("gemini-1.5-flash", "GeminiApiKey");
        model = GenerativeModelFutures.from(gm);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String query = emergencyInput.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!query.isEmpty()) {
                    modelCall(query);
                } else {
                    responseView.setText("Por favor ingrese una consulta.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void modelCall(String query) {
        Content content = new Content.Builder()
                .addText(query)
                .build();

        ListenableFuture<GenerateContentResponse> response = model.generateContent(content);
        Futures.addCallback(
                response,
                new FutureCallback<GenerateContentResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(GenerateContentResponse result) {
                        String resultText = result.getText();

                        SpannableStringBuilder spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder();

                        String[] lines = resultText.split("\n");

                        for (String line : lines) {
                            if (line.startsWith("**")) {
                                String boldText = line.replace("**", "");
                                SpannableString spannableBold = new SpannableString(boldText + "\n");
                                spannableBold.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, boldText.length(), 0);
                                spannable.append(spannableBold);
                            } else if (line.startsWith("*")) {
                                String listItem = "• " + line.replace("*", "") + "\n";
                                spannable.append(listItem);
                            } else {
                                spannable.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                        }

                        runOnUiThread(() -> responseView.setText(spannable));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                        runOnUiThread(() -> responseView.setText("Error al obtener respuesta. Intente nuevamente."));
                    }
                }, getMainExecutor());
    }
}


I tried to integrate a tuned model into my emergency app using the Gemini API, by changing the id of the tuned model in the ModelName parameter inside the GenerativeModel. I expected the tuned model to only respond to emergency related queries, but now it doesn't respond to any queries.
I had it print the error via console and I get this:
Unexpected Response:
}
  "error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "You do not have permission to access tuned model tuned Models/ first-aid-123example123.",
 }
}
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
kotlinx.serialization.MissingFieldException:
Field 'details' is required for type with serial name 'com.google.ai.client.generativeai.commo n.server.GRpcError', but it was missing at path:
$.error

And I get this error when I have already added the access to the project:
Project Access Permission
